# Encoding categorical features stored as lists in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series where categorical data stored as lists. I am trying to extract and encode them as categorical features for ML. I am not sure if the `encoders` from `sklearn.preprocessing` or any out of the box solution would work with lists.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'col1': ['yy','xx','zz'],
                   'col2': ['oo','pp','rr'],
                   'cats': [['A','B','C'],
                            ['U','O','T'],
                            ['T','C','U']]
                 })
```

Expected output:

```
id col1 col2 A B C U O T 
0  yy   oo   1 1 1 0 0 0
1  xx   pp   0 0 0 1 1 1
2  zz   rr   0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Second answer

If you only have one column of lists, the explode should still work by handling it separately:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'col1': ['yy','xx','zz'],
                   'col2': ['oo','pp','rr'],
                   'cats': [['A','B','C'],
                            ['U','O','T'],
                            ['T','C','U']]
                 })
>>> indexed = df.set_index('id')
>>> nolists = indexed.drop(columns=['cats'])
>>> exp = indexed['cats'].explode()
>>> enc = pd.crosstab(exp.index, exp)
>>> result = pd.concat([nolists, enc], axis=1).rename_axis(index='id').reset_index()
>>> result
   id col1 col2  A  B  C  O  T  U
0   0   yy   oo  1  1  1  0  0  0
1   1   xx   pp  0  0  0  1  1  1
2   2   zz   rr  0  0  1  0  1  1
```

## First answer

Are you sure that's your expected output? Why are there two `U` columns?

Try this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'cats': [['A','B','C'],
                            ['U','O','T'],
                            ['T','C','U']]
                 })
>>> exp = df.explode('cats')
>>> enc = pd.crosstab(exp['id'], exp['cats'])
>>> enc

cats  A  B  C  O  T  U
id                    
0     1  1  1  0  0  0
1     0  0  0  1  1  1
2     0  0  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: In reality, I have several columns. So, crosstab wouldn't work.

Comment: If you include a minimal dataset which illustrates why this method won't work, along with an expected output, I may be able to adjust the solution.

Comment: the shape of my dataframe is 3000*80. I am looking for a solution that is scalable when # of columns change.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot set `id` as the index, iterate over each column containing lists, create an encoded dataframe like I've shown, and combine the results with a `pd.concat([...], axis=1)`? I see you've added extra columns. What's the expected output?

Comment: I updated the question, do you mind updating the response? It would be easy to follow.

Comment: The expected output still has columns `A B C U O T`. What should be done with `col1`, `col2`, and their lists?

Comment: They're part of the final result. check now pls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243697/discussion-between-kms-and-trianta2).